# Adding multiple files to Modelsim using Quartus

Tags: modelsim, quartus

I have 2 modules and a testbench which i'm connecting the two modules together and experimenting with the outputs. Design passes analysis & synthesis in Quartus, then I'm trying to start RTL simulation from Tools > Run Simulating Tool > RTL Simulation. My top level entity file is "add_b.v" and it has only module add_b in it. In testbench, I'm instantiating another module called "add_v" which is written in "add_v.v". On modelsim, it can't find the corresponding file to "add_v".

Error: add_b_tb.v(10): Module 'add_v' is not defined.

Normally when I try to testbench only the top level entity without "add_v" (so there's add_b.v and add_b_tb.v), it works fine but when I add "add_v" to my testbench, modelsim cannot find the module.

[Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeDnB.png)

This is my project folder. Quartus only load top level design "add_b.v" and testbench "add_b_tb.v" to modelsim but I don't know how can I also include "add_v.v" file since I can only use only one top level entity and one testbench at a time (as far as I know)

It also works fine when I add the "add_v" module to "add_b.v" so there's two modules (add_v and add_b) in the file. Simulation works but I just wonder if there's an easier way because if I had lot's of modules connected on a testbench, it's not a good practice loading all your modules in one verilog file.

Answer (score 0):

just add `include "add_v.v" in the top of testbench file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).